# What is more correct way to ask, "Do the railroads have future?" or "Do railroads have a future?"

Tags: articles

I prefer the first version because when we refer to the dogs as a class we say "the dogs", so the railroads should be the same. But I was corrected towards the second variant.

Comment: *"Do railroads have a future"* and *"Do the railroads have a future"* are both idiomatic English. But we don't say *"have future"*.

Comment: But we don’t.  Dogs as a class are ***Dogs***.  Dogs make the best pet.  Or do you mean “The dog” (no ‘s’):  “The dog has always been man’s best friend.”

Comment: @Jim why "man's", not "the man's"?

Comment: @Anixx "man" here means "humankind". In this uncountable use, it cannot take an article. "The man's" would have to mean "The male human's", a different meaning of "man" (and would likely retrospectively change the meaning of "the dog" to refer to a particular dog).

Comment: @MikeGraham Why "the dog" as all dogs has an article but "man" as the humankind does not?

Comment: @Anixx when "man" is used to mean "mankind" it is uncountable, so doesn't require an article. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/man

Comment: @JavaLatte The dog is the friend of the human.

Comment: @Anixx grammatically correct but unusual. You are talking about a particular dog, and a particular person, but you are referring to the person as a human.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic  expression is:

> ***[have a/no future](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/have-a-no-future)***
>
> to have a chance or no chance of being successful or continuing
>
> - Does this school have a future?

(Longman Dictionnary)

> Do railroads have a future>

Comment: The answer may be different on each side of the pond.  In the US, "do railroads have a future" refers to railroads in general, as an abstract class.  "do the railroads have a future" would be used in a context where some specific list of railroads had been previously established.  In this case the refence is to those specific railroads.

Comment: @WalterMitty - the OP appears to be referring  to railroads as a general class.

Comment: This side of the pond we call them 'railways', and in case anyone wonders, they definitely do have a thriving present and promising future.